# MemoryMappedViewAccessor WriteArray<T> and ReadArray<T> UnmanagedMemoryAccessor, Are these suppose to be used in methods marked unsafe?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, memory-mapped-files

Both the  MemoryMappedViewAccessor WriteArray and ReadArray methods are marked as UnmanagedMemoryAccessor. Does that mean it is best to uses these methods in a method marked unsafe? I tried both these methods in communication between two applications in methods NOT marked unsafe and they worked. The ReadArray was in a task thread method in one application, while the WriteArray was in the main thread of the other application.

Comment: There is nothing that actually uses `unsafe` pointers here, so no you don't need to. It is "unsafe" in the literal sense of "not being safe" as in "here be dragons".

Comment: C#'s unsafe context is specifically for pointers.